# Inserting String as Elements to the DOM for javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a test chunk of HTML, as an example::

The HTML is a string, and not a DOM element, but I'm trying to see if there i a way, or an approach that can be used to insert the string as the DOM, so it can be appended to the DOM.

```
var test='<tr class="rowHeaders">';
test=test+'<td id="sTD" name="sTD" width="4%">test.php</td>'
test=test+'<td width="2%"><input type="radio" name="tb" ></td>';
test=test+'<td id="tTD" name="tTD" width="2%">php</td>';
test=test+'<td width="2%"><input type="button" name="vv" ></td>';
test=test+'</tr>';


var scriptTBL=document.getElementById("scriptsT");

scriptTBL.children[0].appendChild(test);
```

Trying to do something like this...

But "test" isn't a valid node, or element, so how can i add it to the element??

I thought about using the innerHtml, but there might already be an existing child for the table/tbody for the DOM.

I've been exploring fragments, but this isn't clicking!

The test html has the tbl:

```
<table id="scriptsT" name="scriptsT" >
  <tr>
    .
    .
```

Pointers or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `div` (or `span` or whatever) and load your fragment with innerHTML.

```
var someDiv = document.createElement("div");
someDiv.innerHTML = "<tr ....  ";
someParentElement.appendChild(someDiv);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could append to the `innerHTML`:

```
scriptTBL.tBodies[0].innerHTML += test;
```

---

`foo += bar` is shorthand for `foo = foo + bar`. You can also simplify your HTML creation code this way. Use `test += 'html here';`.

`appendChild` only accepts a DOM element.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary DOM interaction (and strangeness over unclosed tags), you should append to a string variable, and then set innerHTML with the full string when you're done.

Comment: @Zach: Yes, the `test` in `scriptTBL.tBodies[0].innerHtml += test` is meant to be the final `test` variable... but you are right in pointing it out.

Comment: I see -- that makes sense. Also, I think it should be .innerHTML, not .innerHtml.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var test = '<tr class="rowHeaders">';
test = test + '<td id="sTD" name="sTD" width="4%">test.php</td>'
test = test + '<td width="2%"><input type="radio" name="tb" ></td>';
test = test + '<td id="tTD" name="tTD" width="2%">php</td>';
test = test + '<td width="2%"><input type="button" name="vv" ></td>';
test = test + '</tr>';

var discardableElement = document.createElement("div");
discardableElement.innerHtml = test;

var scriptTBL = document.getElementById("scriptsT");
scriptTBL.tBodies[0].appendChild(discardableElement.firstChild);
```

It's a little wasteful, since you're creating a DOM element (which is an expensive operation) only to discard it, but it will create the DOM elements to allow you to use the `appendChild` method.

Alternatively, you could use string concatenation to use the innerHtml property, like this:

```
var test = '<tr class="rowHeaders">';
test = test + '<td id="sTD" name="sTD" width="4%">test.php</td>'
test = test + '<td width="2%"><input type="radio" name="tb" ></td>';
test = test + '<td id="tTD" name="tTD" width="2%">php</td>';
test = test + '<td width="2%"><input type="button" name="vv" ></td>';
test = test + '</tr>';


var scriptTBL = document.getElementById("scriptsT");

// Insert at the BOTTOM of the table
var newHtml = scriptTBL.innerHtml + test;

// OR... Insert at the top of the table
//var newHtml =  test + scriptTBL.innerHtml;

scriptTBL.tBodies[0].innerHtml = newHtml;
```

**EDIT:** Updated based on @Zach's comment.

Comment: I think @Zach meant something different. `scriptTBL.innerHtml += newHtml` *is* `scriptTBL.innerHtml = scriptTBL.innerHtml + newHtml;`

Comment: @Felix - Yeah that's what I figured too after I made the edits (I feel stupid in hindsight), but it looks prettier this way.